# How to create n-level (multi-level, cascading) dependent dropdown (selects, options)?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, json

Purpose: To find the easiest and more flexible way creating cascading dropdown lists, using tools jquery(javascript), php, mysql;

If you have other easier/flexible options then please, share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select class="step1 step" name="step1"></select>
<select class="step2 step" name="step2"></select>
<select class="step3 step" name="step3"></select>
<select class="step4 step" name="step4"></select>
<select class="step5 step" name="step5"></select>
```

For information purposes, usually on last dropdown is selected:

```
<textarea id="info" disabled=""></textarea>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    var options = function(data, level, selected) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var pid = $('.step'+(level-1)).val();

            if(pid == item.pid || item.pid == 0) {
                if(!$('.step').find('option[value='+item.id+']').length) {
                    $('.step'+level).append($('<option>', {
                        value: item.id,
                        text : item.name,
                        info: item.info,
                    }));
                }

                if(item.childs)
                    options(item.childs, level+1);
            }
        });

        var info = $('.step option:selected:last').attr('info');
        $('#info').val(info);
    }
    options(data, 1);

    $('.step').change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $(this).nextAll('.step').empty();

        options(data, 1);
    });
});
```

**JSON**

```
{"1":{"id":"1","name":"Category-1","info":"","pid":"0","childs":{"3":{"id":"3","name":"Category-1-2","info":"","pid":"1","childs":{"19":{"id":"19","name":"Captiva","info":"Some text","pid":"3"}}}}}}
```

and so on ...

**PHP**

```
foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
    $info[$value->id] = $value;
    unset($info[0]);
}

foreach($info as $key => $val)
    $childs[$val->pid][$key] = $val;

foreach($info as $item)
    if (isset($childs[$item->id]))
        $item->childs = $childs[$item->id];

$total = count($info);
foreach($info as $key => $val){
    if($info[$key]->pid != 0)
        unset($info[$key]);
}
```

**MYSQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dropdown_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```